# Reading 2 columns of doubles in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

I don't know how it can register my doubles.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("TwoRows.txt"));

double total1=0;
double total2=0;
List<Double> l1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> l2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

while (s.hasNextDouble()) {
    l1.add(s.nextDouble());
    l2.add(s.nextDouble());
}

for (double x: l1){
    total1 += x;
}
for (double x: l2){
    total2 += x;
}
System.out.println(l1);
System.out.println(l2);
System.out.println(total1);
System.out.println(total2);
```

The file looks like this:

```
12.4 12.2
15.2 19.3
12.2 17.3
17.1 15.4
9.2  10.2
10.3 3.3
```

Comment: what do you mean by "registering your doubles"?

Comment: what is your error, what is the expected behaviour, what is going wrong? so many questions...

Comment: I want to calculate the mean of the two columns, and output the answer on the console.

Comment: I did it thanks to @Kai suggestion:

Comment: `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TwoRows.txt"))) {
   String line;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] twoDoubles = line.split("\\s+");
      l1.add(Double.parseDouble(twoDoubles[0]));
      l2.add(Double.parseDouble(twoDoubles[1]));      
     }
   }
  System.out.println(l1);
  System.out.println(l2);
  for (double x: l1){
   total1 += x;
  }
  for (double x: l2){
   total2 += x;
  }
  total1 /= l1.size();
  total2 /= l2.size();
  System.out.println(total1);
  System.out.println(total2);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is read the file. For that you can use this part of the code:

```
File finput = new File("yourfile");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(finput));
```

Then what you want to do is read line by line and split each line with thanks to the space character.

```
String line ;
String[] linesplit ;
double d1, d2 ;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    linesplit = line.split("\\s+");
    d1 = Double.parseDouble(linesplit[0]);
    d2 = Double.parseDouble(linesplit[1]);
    // Some more code
}
```

This way you can read through your file and do whatever it is that you want to do with your doubles.
If you are not sure

Comment: Look at the time when the answer was posted that was before you posted your code even though I made some edits afterwards but I posted code before you so no ;).

Comment: But you just edited your answer with some code (before it was just text), look at the edit time ;)

Comment: @Kai My first answer with code already was 11 minutes ago, your edit adding the code was 7 minutes ago. So please make sure to check everything before throwing some accusations like that ... If anything I should be the one complaining since you created the code after me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but I think reading the file line by line and splitting each line by white space and then parsing the two values to `Double` is a much better approach here.

*try this code:*

```
double total1 = 0;
double total2 = 0;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TwoRows.txt"))) {
String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] twoDoubles = line.split("\\s+");
   total1 += Double.parseDouble(twoDoubles[0]);
   total2 += Double.parseDouble(twoDoubles[1]);      
  }
}

System.out.println(total1);
System.out.println(total2);
```

Be careful with the `twoDoubles[n]` it only works that way if each line contains **exactly** two doubles - otherwise an *Out Of Range Exception* will be thrown. Better check for array size.